# Where would I find a PayPal users PayPal_id?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working with the PayPal Node.js SDK and I am trying to payout a user. In order to do that I can use either their email, phone number or encrypted PayPal ID. We would prefer to work with encrypted data as much as possible. Where would we find a users `paypal_ID`?

If any of our code would help us find this information, we can post it just tell us what you need. Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score -1):

It should be displayed in the account overview page or in the profile.  It typically shows your PayPal account email and merchant account ID.

It can also be obtained via the [GetPalDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetPalDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), but that's not REST.  I'm not sure if REST has an equivalent API yet or not.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, it doesn't actually answer my question. I'm not looking for help navigating the PayPal website, I am having trouble programmatically sending people money. The crux of my problem is finding the encrypted account number. Can you help with that?

Comment: Well, the way to find it programmatically is to use the GetPalDetails API.  Not sure how else to say it.  I would probably build a simple PHP web service that pulls the ID from PayPal that I could then hit from within a Javascript app any time I need to.  I don't know if you'd be using PHP or some other language, though, and you never mentioned needing help with code.  You just asked where to find the ID, and my answer is still the same.